# How to access to the playstore of another counrty just by changing URL and without using VPN

Tags: android, url, google-play, country, mobile-country-code

i want to access to the google play store of other counties to see what's new in, i want to know how to write the url of play store of brazil for example when i'm in france or any other counrty, just by writing the url because the vpn don't allow a lot of countries and changing in the setting of the playstore account allows it only one time per year
i want just to see without any account
what's wrong in this url
https://play.google.com/store/apps/category/DATING/collection/topselling_free?hl=pt&gl=BR
il the past 2 mounths, it was working but now it gives me a 404 error[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3rpcx.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can use Skyzip extention for Google chrome after installing it just on it and open play store you IP will be changing its use Proxy and you can open play store